# "if any" function won't check if strings in lists match user input. Python

Tags: python, if-statement

So my program will ask the user for their emotional state that is contained in this variable:

```
emotional_state = input("How are you? ")
```

Beneath the input variable I have two lists filled with strings of available responses:

```
positive_emotion = ["good","okay", "great", "fine", "awesome", "fine thanks", "great thanks", "happy"]
negative_emotion = ["bad","not so good", "unhappy", "sad", "lonely", "depressed", "sick", "ill", "suicidal"]
```

The rest of the code is a series of if statements for the outputs, based on the word from the lists used.

```
if any([emotion in emotional_state for emotion in positive_emotion]):
    print("I'm happy to hear that :)")
elif any([emotion in emotional_state for emotion in negative_emotion]):
    print("Aww hopefully I can make you feel better :)")
else:
    print("I didn't quite catch that but let's move on, okay?")
```

The majority of the available responses gives the desired response however when I use a word for the input which is similar to a word from the other list, I get a response for the opposite emotion. Here is a desired output for example,

```
How are you? good
I'm happy to hear that :)
```

Now here is the bug or error that I've run into,

```
How are you? not so good 
I'm happy to hear that :)
```

It's as if the user input `"not so good"` (despite being from the `negative_emotion` list), because it contains the word `"good"`, which is also in the `positive_emotion` list, is likely being mistaken for a `positive_emotion`.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem or have any solution?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: "Does anyone know what is causing this problem or have any solution?" You just said it in the previous paragraph: it contains something that is in the `positive_emotion` list. The `if` condition is checked before the `elif`, and if it's satisfied, the `elif` is skipped. That's how the construct works, and how it's intended to work.

Comment: More generally, an approach like this is going to be fragile. Properly understanding natural language is a *much* more complicated task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Karl Knechtel . However, for this particular example, I noticed two ways to improve your program and solve the bugs:

1. You are incorrectly using any(). Any is currently looping through all *letters* of the word. You need to create a list by splitting the phrase into a list of `words`. Does that make sense?
2. You need additional to avoid bugs for phrases like "not so good", which I have added after `and` in the first `if` and `or` after the first `elif`.

   ```
   emotional_state = input("How are you? ")
   emotional_state_split = emotional_state.split(" ")
   positive_emotion = ["good","okay", "great", "fine", "awesome", "fine thanks", "great thanks", "happy"]
   negative_emotion = ["bad","not so good", "unhappy", "sad", "lonely", "depressed", "sick", "ill", "suicidal"]
   for emotion in emotional_state_split:
       print(emotion)
   if any([emotion in emotional_state_split for emotion in positive_emotion]) and emotional_state not in negative_emotion:
       print("I'm happy to hear that :)")
   elif any([emotion in emotional_state_split for emotion in negative_emotion]) or emotional_state in negative_emotion:
       print("Aww hopefully I can make you feel better :)")
   else:
       print("I didn't quite catch that but let's move on, okay?")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you flipped the logic. `emotion in state` looked through the state to find `good` in `not so good`.

```
positive_emotion = ["good","okay", "great", "fine", "awesome", "fine thanks", "great thanks", "happy"]
negative_emotion = ["bad","not so good", "unhappy", "sad", "lonely", "depressed", "sick", "ill", "suicidal"]

def check(state):
    if any([state in emotion   for emotion in positive_emotion]):
        print("great")
    elif any([state in emotion  for emotion in negative_emotion]):
        print("sorry")
    else:
        print("huh?")

check("good")        
check("awesome")
check("not so good") 
check("dobro")
```

output:

```
great
great
sorry
huh?
```